# AngularJS component template switching

Tags: angularjs

I've looked around and haven't found an answer that works for me. I have a component, built with John Papa's style guide in mind, that shows uploaded photos to the user.

I want to implement a number of views, similar to how an Windows, MacOS allows you to switch between detailed, thumbnail, list views.

Because the views are so different and to keep the code in a maintainable state I'd  like to keep these templates in separate files.

So how should I implement this?

The different approaches are:

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
            if (tAttrs.type) {
                if (tAttrs.type === 'thumb') {
                    return 'thumbnail.html';
                }
                if (tAttrs.type === 'list') {
                    return 'list.html';
                }
                if (tAttrs.type === 'detail') {
                    return 'detail.html';
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The problem here is that the template is decided early on and can't be changed until a refresh.

```
 <ng-switch on="post.viewMode">
    <ng-switch when="thumbnail" ng-include="'./thumbnail.html'">
    <ng-switch when="list" ng-include="'/list.html'">
    <ng-switch when="detail" ng-include="'/detail.html'">
</ng-switch>
```

this seems to be the best but ng-include creates a new scope which throws off my component structure, everything must be accessed via scope.$parent.variable

The last option is to put all three views into the same html template file and use ng-if to use the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, template/templateUrl function is wrong way, there's no scope or interpolated attributes which are commonly seen as the way to control directive behaviour.

As some other built-in directives, `ng-include` is a quick way to get around ('declarative programming' they call it) but also is opinionated PITA exactly because of the reason noted above - it forces inherited scope even if you don't want it.

```
.directive('myDirective', function ($templateRequest, $compile) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var prevTplName;
            var templates = {
                thumb: 'thumbnail.html',
                // ...
            }

            attrs.$observe('type', setTemplate);

            function setTemplate(tplName) {
                if (!templates.hasOwnProperty(tplName) || prevTplName === tplName)
                    return;

                $templateRequest(templates[tplName]).then(function (response) {
                    var contents = $compile(response)(scope);
                    element.empty().append(contents);
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```